# HTML Entity displaying wrong in Camino

Tags: html, entity, camino

I'm trying to show the characters ☜ and ☞ in my HTML page. Every single browser I've tested displays them properly, except for (inexplicably) Camino. Instead, it shows this:

[☜ http://b2.s3.p.quickshareit.com/files/picture1a9745.png](http://b2.s3.p.quickshareit.com/files/picture1a9745.png)

That's what it renders for ☜. The symbol it shows for ☞ is similar.

If for some reason you can't see those characters properly, here's the HTML entities I'm using:

```
&#9756; and &#9758;
```

Now, Camino is a Mac-only browser that use Gecko. However, All the versions of Firefox that I've tested work just fine, and my main browser is Safari on a Mac.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Really? Someone actually tests for Camino compatibility?

Comment: I use litmusapp.com, it makes it really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this was a bug in Firefox 2 which uses the rendering engine that Camino uses.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=229547&action=edit

Comment: That's odd, because I tested in Firefox 2.0 (although on Windows), and it works fine there. You very well may be right, however. I may end up replacing it with an image in the end.

Comment: The bug was Mac-specific (font code is an area where Gecko bugs are often not cross-platform)

Also, as a slight correction to the answer, the rendering engine is Gecko 1.8.1, which is used by both Firefox 2 and Camino 1.x. Firefox is a browser, not a rendering engine.

Comment: Yes, I meant that Camino uses the same rendering engine as Firefox, not that Firefox is a rendering engine.